# PHP - Returning all parents of a value that may or may not exist within an multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have an array like the following:

```
array(
    'men' => array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => 'John',
            'age' => 21
        ),
        1 => array(
            'name' => 'Alex',
            'age' => 19
        ),
        2 => array(
            'name' => 'Bob',
            'age' => 21
        )
    )
)
```

How could I return, for example, all the parent keys of the value 21. So, in this example it would return 0 and 2.

Comment: array_search http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php there is an example for multidimensional arrays in the user notes.

Answer (score 2):

Either use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php). Or you could use something like this.

```
foreach ($array['men'] as $index=>$value) {
    if ($value['age']==21) echo $index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array['men'] as $key => $val) {
    if (in_array('21', $val))
        $result[] = $key;
}
```